# C# Web API Forms Authentication cookie not getting set in Angular Project

Tags: c#, angularjs, authentication, model-view-controller, gulp

My Angular Project is running on a node server

http://localhost:3000/login

Then I have a local C# Web API project with the following URL Structure in IIS

http://localhost/MyProject/API/Login

I am trying to add forms authentication for client side Login and it all seems to be fine,except I can't see cookie being set in my client side project.

In my API project in web config I have set as this

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" name="__MyProjectAuth" />
    </authentication>
```

And then in my api login controller I call

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, logInModel.RememberMe);
```

Which doesn't throw an error, in my Response header the Set-Cookie contains the cookie but it never actually gets created in my browser.

Gulp Serve Settings

```
var options = {
        proxy: 'localhost:' + port,
        port: 3000,
        files: isDev ? [
            config.client + '**/*.*',
            '!' + config.less,
            config.temp + '**/*.css'
        ] : [],
        ghostMode: { // these are the defaults t,f,t,t
            clicks: true,
            location: false,
            forms: true,
            scroll: true
        },
        injectChanges: true,
        logFileChanges: true,
        logLevel: 'info',
        logPrefix: 'hottowel',
        notify: true,
        reloadDelay: 0 //1000
    } ;
```

What am I missing, anything I can set on adding the cookie to maybe certain domain with port like localhost:3000 ?

Edit :

Opening Chrome Like this seem to work, but I would like a better solution

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

Comment: How do you plan to host those two application after implementing them? I'm sure you already know that you cannot host them in two different domains due to cookie security.

Comment: Aye, its a pure development problem. I thought this would be common problem with front end projects all using grunt/gulp these days and calling web api projects but guess not. Very annoying !

Comment: Already tested it with a "build" version of the site and no issues at all.

Comment: Since the updated question is about how to use chrome, you might want to consider asking at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) to get more answer.

Comment: It's not really about chrome this is issue across all browsers.

Comment: It is not a common problem, because most Angular developer doesn't use cookie based Form Authentication *(more than 10 years old technology)* if they use pure Web API. In a nutshell, we do not use cookie based Authentication at all, if we plan to host in two different domains. As I answered, we use Token Based Authentication with AngularJS in Web API.

Comment: @StevieB did you got the answer for this question? because i'm stuck in same situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can search information about Cross-Domain.

You need to set this code in Web.config of ASP WebApi:

```
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Tried this getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/myproject/api/user/login/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match '*, *,*').